# SQL Server: Issue on Data Return

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

As a novice SQL Server user, I ran into a problem that I did not know a solution to. I am trying to draw a master list of items and their cost. Some items have component items with their own cost, and those need to be called as well. However, whenever I try to include the component items, the query does not return items without components.

For example: I call 3 items from the query: A, B, and C. It displays their costs perfectly. However, I learn that Item C has a Component Item X. When I try to add a column for component item and it's cost, Items A and B are not returned in the query as they do not have a component item. I can't figure out why a NULL isn't placed when an item does not have a component item to accompany it.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    T1.item_no, T2.item_cost, T1.component_item_no, T2.item_cost(2)
FROM 
    T1 
INNER JOIN 
    T2 ON T2.item_no = T1.item_no
INNER JOIN 
    T2(2) ON T2.item_no = T1.component_item_no
```

I had to call T2 twice so I could call item cost for both the top level item as well as it's component.

Sample return data:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @jarlh added some a sample of the result I want vs. the result I receive.

Comment: You should add it in the text of the question, not as an image. Why? I am at work now and they block externally hosted images so I just get a big X. It also allows us to copy and paste as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN for the component item table

Comment: Both or just one of them?

Comment: @GHINOTE, why not try all versions, and see what differs? Great way to learn SQL.

Comment: That's not going to help him... SQL by trial and error just wastes everyones time

Comment: the one with join on component_item_no - T2(2)

Comment: Keep in mind what the 2 mean. An inner join means show me data in both. The Left join is going to show all data. So you Inner join when it will always have a match and left join when their could be a match

Comment: If you want T2.item_cost(2) as zero when there is no component item use ISNULL(T2.item_cost(2),0)